# Can anyone help me write a sql query

Tags: sql, postgresql, netezza

```
jkdfhdjfhjh&name=ijkjkjkjkjkjk&id=kdjkjkjkjkjkjjjd&class=kdfjjfjdhfjhf
```

The above string has some characters starting with & and ending with =
for example we have &name= and I just need this from the above string.

similarly I need &id=, &class=

I need the output under a single column.

```
Final Extract
----------------------
&id=, &class=, &name=
```

can anyone help me out in writing a query for this.

Comment: Which SQL dialect exactly? PostgreSQL? Regular Expressions are not part of the ANSI SQL standard AFAIK.

Comment: Is there no server-side language you can use? In most of them, this would be one function call.

Comment: so the string in a field in a SQL database, right? Does the solution need to be pure SQL? I'd consider it much easier to achieve this in another language.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this :

```
select regexp_replace('jkdfhdjfhjh&name=ijkjkjkjkjkjk&id=kdjkjkjkjkjkjjjd&class=kdfjjfjdhfjhf', '\\w*?(&.*?=)\\w+((?=&)|$)', '\\1, ', 'g');
```

result:

```
     regexp_replace
-------------------------
 &name=, &id=, &class=,
```

Then it's up to you to remove the last `,`.

The regexp_replace function is available in version 8.1 and after.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the values along with each variable, I would implement this by splitting on "&" into an array and then taking a slice of the desired elements:

```
SELECT (string_to_array('jkdfhdjfhjh&name=ijkjkjkjkjkjk&id=kdjkjkjkjkjkjjjd&class=kdfjjfjdhfjhf','&'))[2:4];
```

Output in PostgreSQL 8.4 (array type):

```
{name=ijkjkjkjkjkjk,id=kdjkjkjkjkjkjjjd,class=kdfjjfjdhfjhf}
```

The example string is very wide so here's the general form to show the array slicing more clearly:

```
SELECT ((string_to_array(input_field,'&'))[2:4];
```

NOTE: You must have the extra parentheses around the string_to_array() call in order for the array slicing to work--you'll get an error otherwise.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that after I posted, but I assumed otherwise as I couldn't figure out what the use was of parsing out the field names and throwing away the associated values...